# linkbutton style

Tags: css, linkbutton

i'm making a workbook creator in C#.net ( using  visual studio )

the book is build from the text part and the question part.

all the answers for the question are in side the text and the user need to click on the right answer.
if he's right then the word become green and if he's wrong it become red.

i'm using linkbutton for this and i need it to be without and "link" style.

i use this code for the question part:

```
public class question
{

public void createQusetion(Panel leftside, string text, string question,string answer)
{
    string[] Qbuttonstext = text.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < Qbuttonstext.Length; i++)
    {
        LinkButton answerButton = new LinkButton();
        if (Qbuttonstext[i] == answer)
        {
            answerButton.ID = "answer";
        }
        else
        {
            answerButton.ID = "word" + i.ToString();
        }
        answerButton.Text = Qbuttonstext[i].ToString()+" ";
        answerButton.CssClass = "textbuttonB4";

   answerButton.Click += new EventHandler(checkAnswer);

     leftside.Controls.Add(answerButton);
    }


}
}
```

i used css stylesheet and used this code:

```
.textbuttonB4 a:link
{
   style:none;
   color:Black;
   font-size:18px;
   border-bottom-style:none;
   background-color:transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.textbuttonB4 a:hover
{
  style:none;
   color:Black;
   font-size:18px;
   border-bottom-style:none;
   background-color:transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.textbuttonB4 a:visited
{
    style:none;
   color:Black;
   font-size:18px;
    border-bottom-style:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

when the code running the text is still appears as a link.

after looking the web for solution, dont konw why its not working.

sorry for the previous version of this question.

asaf

Comment: Your question makes no effort to explain which tools you are working with. Also, "for some reason it doesn't work" tells us nothing.

Comment: I agree with Nathan. Please add a testcase or give further information.

Comment: sorry for this, i've changed the question. 

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the output source. Does the button have the appropriate class? Did you remember to include the stylesheet?

Also, what does `style:none;` do? It's not valid CSS.

Comment: the "style:none" is a mistake.
i viewed the source code and the class is OK, and stylesheet is included. all the other CSS styling is working.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? From what I can see, the styles for `:link`, `:visited` and `:hover` are exactly the same, and I don't see any changes to that in your backend code.

Comment: thanks every one for the comments, 
i've solved it by deleting the 'a:link' from the class declaration

thank you all